# How to access private attributes of a class?

Tags: rspec

I can't access the private attributes/variables of an object for testing in rspec

I've learned that you can access private methods like this:

```
 expect(CLASS.send(METHOD_AS_SIMBOL,PARAM1,PARAM2…)).to eq(EXPECTED_RESULT)
```

But I can't make it work for attributes

Edit:

I feel uncomfortable with the idea of not testing private methods and attributes. I've read about not testing private code is beneficial because it forces the programmer to simplify classes and follow the Single responsibility principle.

But somehow I feel the need to do it. It makes me feel that my code will be more solid if I test 100% of it. And I don't like the idea of being forced to follow some guidance by sacrificing what I perceive as code quality. I might be wrong though.

Edit 2

I don't want to test methods. I already know how to do it. Just instance variables.

Comment: Do you want to test methods or variables (the approach would be quite different)? Why do you want to test private methods in the first place? Can you please elaborate and add an example of what you actually want to test.

Comment: Check the edit of the OP. I did it trying to answer you questions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not convinced to test directly a `private method` be a good practice, you should considerate to test only the method which call your `private method`.

Moreover you want to test attributes used by your `private method` but the code you write is going to test your `private method` result.

I guess you don't need to test attributes. For example:

```
def my_method a, b
  a + b
end
```

Could be test on this Way

```
expect(my_method(2, 10)).to eq 12
```

As you kow what is the behaviour of your method does not matters the values of your attributes, the important part is your result.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help to get the private attributes

Answer (score 1):

I would consider testing private, internal variables of a class a code smell that adds no benefit and makes future refactorings much harder.

But if you really want to do it then you can use [`instance_variable_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) to get the value of an instance variable like this:

```
expect(object.instance_variable_get(:@variable_name)).to eq('expected value')
```